# How to pass data to child component in Vue

Tags: vue.js

Im trying to pass data as props from parent to its child component, but as it is it doesnt work and I cant find what is wrong. Is the way I do it wrong and should I do it differently?

Parent:

```
<a-course-select :courses="courses"></a-course-select>

...

data() {
    return {
        courses: null,
...
methods: {
        async campSelected(courses) {
            this.courses = courses
            console.log(this.courses) // this works, I can console log courses
        },
```

Child:

```
<a-course
            v-for="course in allCourses"
            :key="course.id"
            :name="course.name"
>...

export default {
    components: {
        ACourse,
    },
    props: ['courses'],
    data() {
        return {
            allCourses: this.courses,
        }
    },
}
```

Comment: Try to use `courses` on child component instead of `allCourses` in `v-for`

Comment: @7-zete-7 it works, but i dont understand why

Answer (score 4):

`allCourses: this.courses` accesses a prop once on assignment so it's `null`, this should only be done with props that are expected to be static values.

If a prop is expected to change, it should be accessed only in a computed or watcher in component script section:

```
...
computed: {
   allCourses() { return this.courses }
},
...
```

Since `courses` and `allCourses` values are the same, `courses` prop could be accessed directly in the template.